# MVC with angular 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular2-routing

I develop project mvc with angular 2. I use Identity in project. I have view of login after authorization I want redirect on my angular page.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ApplicationUser user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.Email, model.Password);
            if (user == null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "login ...");
            }
            else
            {
                ClaimsIdentity claim = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user,
                                        DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
                AuthenticationManager.SignOut();
                AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties
                {
                    IsPersistent = true
                }, claim);
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                return Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
        }
        ViewBag.returnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View(model);
    }
```

Here my RouteConfig

```
          routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Logout",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Logout", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );          

        routes.MapRoute(
           name: "Default",
            url: "{*anothing}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                    );
```

When redirecting, I do not go to the address /home of angular page is redirect on /Home/Index

> RedirectToAction("Index", "Home")
>   Here my angular routing

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [    
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: 'home', component: HomeComponent }
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

Help me please, how I can do it right?

Here my index page and layout

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<body>
    <user-app>Loading…</user-app>
</body>

//////////////////
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8" />
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
     @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
     @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
     <script src="/node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
     <script src="/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
     <script src="/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
     <script src="/systemjs.config.js"></script>
     <script>
        System.import('app').catch(function (err) { console.error(err); });
     </script>
 </head>
<body>
   <div class="container body-content">        
       @RenderBody()
       <hr />

       <footer>
           <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
       </footer>
   </div>

     @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
     @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
     @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: What do you mean you "get download"? which URL you are referred to after log-in? can you share the action "Index" on home controller?

Comment: @ZivWeissman after log-in I get /Home/Index url

Comment: @ZivWeissman my angular page displayed only then when I launch in debugging my _Layout.cshtml

Comment: Can you post your: 1. index.cshtml (Home page view) 2. _Layout.cshtml

Comment: @ZivWeissman I updated my question